# Integrating by parts

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, polarization, integration, vector-fields

I am having little trouble with my professor's note.

$$F=-\int{(dr)}{(\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{P}) \vec{E} }=\int{(dr)}{(\vec{P} \cdot \vec{\nabla} ) \vec{E} }$$

where F is force, P is polarization, and E is Electric field. 
I am not sure how to use integration by part here. Integration is over negative infinity to positive infinity.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: F is force, P is polarization, and E is Electronic field. Thank you, I will add on the post

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegrationByParts.aspx

Comment: For vectors A, B note the identity $\nabla \cdot ({A} {B}) = (\nabla \cdot A) B + (A \cdot \nabla) B$, after that recall your Gauss theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confused due to the vectorial form of the equation, so you should write it by components (I will use cartesian coordinates), and I will use $\partial_x = \dfrac{d}{dx}$ for comfort, that being said, your equation can be written as:

$$ F=-\int{(dr)}{(\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{P}) \vec{E} }=-\int{(dr)}{(\partial_x P_x +\partial_y P_y + \partial_z P_z ) \vec{E} } $$

By expanding the gradient. Then you can split the equation by components, so for the $\hat i$ component you have

$$ -\hat i \int (dr) (\partial_x P_x + \partial_y P_y + \partial_z P_z) E_x = - \hat i \int (dr) (E_x \partial_x P_x + E_x \partial_y P_y + E_z \partial_z P_z)$$

now you can integrate by parts for each term, so you get (for the first term)

$$ -\hat i \int (dr) E_x \partial_x P_x = -\hat i (E_x P_x) + \hat i \int(P_x\partial_x E_x) = \hat i \int P_x\partial_xE_x$$

Since the polarization and the electric field vanish at infinity. Now you can do the same for the other terms, which nets you

$$ \hat i \int (P_x \partial_x + P_y\partial_y + P_z \partial_x) E_x = \hat i \int (\vec P \cdot \vec\nabla ) E_x $$

Since you can do exactly the same procedure for very missing term you have

$$ F=-\int{(dr)}{(\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{P}) \vec{E} }=\int{(dr)}{(\vec{P} \cdot \vec{\nabla} ) \vec{E} } $$